# DHCP seems to fail very frequently unless I use tcpdump

Tags: networking, dhcp

On my Ubuntu 14.04 system, many connections (especially wireless ones) seem to simply time out. However, if I run `tcpdump` on the interface before attempting to connect, they almost always connect speedily. (I did this to try and see what was causing the problem - but it fixes it; it seems putting the interface into promiscuous mode alters something). There's precious little in the kernel log files.

How can I investigate/diagnose what's going wrong? Or any ideas how to fix this?